# Make an animation execute a certain amount of times based on a variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know my fiddle is kind of messy, but it wasn't working without all of this code. I need to make it so that clicking the button will cause the h2 in the radial progress bar to count down, animate once every time it counts down and execute another battle with the selected monster until the amount of autoLeft reaches zero in which case autoLeft will reset and battling will stop until the button is clicked again.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1bb1225/1/)

```
var oneAction = function() {
    var round = 0;
    monsterEl = $('#monsterList option:selected');
    monster = monsterEl.data('monster');
  $('.progress').addClass('activated activatedAfter');
  $('#autos').text(player.autoLeft);
  $('#dam').empty();
  $('#monsterdam').empty();
  while(monster.hp > 0 && player.hp > 0 && round < 20) {
      $('#monsterdam').append("</p>The " + $('#monsterList').val() + " has hit you for " + monster.monsterDam() + " damage</p>");
      player.hp -= monster.monsterDam();
    $('#dam').append("</p>You have hit the " + $('#monsterList').val() + " for " + monster.playerDam() + " damage</p>");
    monster.hp -= monster.playerDam();
    round +=1;
        if(round >=20) {
            $('#monsterdam').append("</p>The battle has timed out</p>");
            $('#dam').append("</p>The battle has timed out</p>");
        }
  }
  if(monster.hp <= 0){
  $('#dam').append("<p>You have defeated the " + $('#monsterList').val() + ", you have received " + monster.exp + " experience and " + monster.gold + " gold!</p>");
    monster.hp = monster.fullLife;
    player.hp = player.fullLife;
    player.exp += monster.exp;
    player.gold += monster.gold;
    player.nextLevel -= monster.exp;
    player.implement();
    if(player.exp >= player.expNeeded) {
        lvlUp();
    }
}
if(player.hp <= 0){
$('#monsterdam').append("<p>The " + $('#monsterList').val() + " has defeated you!</p>");
  monster.hp = monster.fullLife;
  player.hp = player.fullLife;
}
}

$('#battleButton').click(function() {
    //playerDam()
    if(player.autoLeft > 0) {
        oneAction();
        player.autoLeft -= 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for a fix to your Javascript loop (or) to make your animation run everytime the button is clicked? Making the animation run everytime the button is clicked is easy and I can answer that but your JS is very messy and there is a lot of code and so fixing the loop is a big effort.

Comment: No I want one click to make the animation run and the oneAction function to run 20 times which is equivalent to player.auto so if player.auto were equal to 50, then the animation and function would run 50 times on one button click